# sql - count of two colums

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, grafana

i put in a database many line and i have this :

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| ID | time                | os_name     | program        | last_line |
+----+---------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| 14 | 2019-01-04 14:00:00 | titi        | roro           | 109       |
| 15 | 2019-01-04 14:00:00 | titi        | roro           | 109       |
| 16 | 2019-01-04 14:00:00 | gege        | fefe           | 109       |
```

i want :

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| time                | nb_os_name_program      | os_name     | program   | last_line |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2019-01-04 14:00:00 |                      2  | titi        | roro      | 109       |
| 2019-01-04 14:00:00 |                      1  | gege        | fefe      | 109       |
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  What is the logic behind the timestamp value in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Simple `GROUP BY` with aggregation would help you :

```
SELECT time, os_name, count(*) as nb_os_name, program, lastline, 
FROM table t
GROUP BY time, os_name, program, lastline
```